# How to terminate debugging in XPages

Tags: debugging, xpages

I have configured debugging on our Notes development server and set up a debug configuration in my desktop designer client using this guide;

http://www.intec.co.uk/beginners-guide-to-the-java-debugger-and-tips-from-using-it-and-a-teaser/

It appears to work.  However, the terminate (or stop) debugging option is not enabled.  I can pause the debugging but NOT terminate.  The result is that it makes the Xpages application stall at next login.  How do I terminate a debug session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure which button you're using. The red square for terminate doesn't disconnect the debugger. I think that just stops debugging for the current request. The "disconnect" option is the red icon that looks like a letter "N".

The debugger also disconnects when HTTP restarts.

Comment: Ah!! So I have to disconnect and not simply stop the debug??  This makes sense I suppose if I am remotely debugging on the server.  I see the symbol you mean - it looks like an upper case N with a red dot at the start and end of the letter.

Comment: Just avoid disconnecting or terminating when debugging Java agents in Eclipse. That has a tendency to crash the server (but then I usually develop against a local server)

Comment: Never been exposed to Java agents -just mainly straight forward Java and actually still trying to get the hang of it.  I have had a look and Java agents appear to be for "instrumentation" and have a "premain" method.  I have searched the application for "premain" and there isn't one so it should not be a problem.  Thanks for your assistance